# Node.js error handling through each layer

Tags: design, javascript, node.js, error-handling

I am looking for a way to handle errors in a Node.js application without getting lots of log entries for the same error event, one from each each affected layer.

This might actually apply to any language, but I still don't understand how to do it correctly. The questions are always *who* handles the errors, does it make sense to continually throw to the top, and who logs what?

Let's take a simple example of a user system where you can retrieve users from a database and "log in" if credentials match.

**Database layer**

```
// connects to a mongo db 
class UserDatabase(){
   async getUser(filter){
       // this can throw if connection is dead
       let user = await this.collections.users.findOne(filter);
       return user;
   }
}
```

**Application layer**

```
// makes calls to the db class to "login" a user
class UserApp {
    async loginUser(email, password){
       let user = await this.db.getUser({email});
       if(!user){
           return false;
       }
       if(user.password === options.password){
           return true;
       }
    }
}
```

**REST layer**

```
// calls the API from REST calls
class UserRestApi {
    async loginUser(request, response){
        let result = await this.app.loginUser(request.body.email, request.body.password);
        if(result){
            response.status = 200;
        }
        else {
            response.status = 401;
        }
        response.end();
    }
}
```

At this moment there is 0 error handling. We can fail almost everywhere with uncaught exceptions. But is there ever any point in catching at the lowest level? Suppose `getUser()` fails because the mongodb connection dies. I can catch it and log it there, but then do I throw it again, and again, and again, and log it again, and again, and again? Does that make sense? I would end up in this case with 2-3 repeated logs.

I'm just not sure how to approach this.

Comment: I don't know why your question was downvoted, I believe it's on-topic. Sadly I haven't touched Node.js in over 4 years so I don't know what the best solution is here.

Comment: I don't know. The whole point of this site used to be about asking questions. Now it's really just about being the first to mark duplicates or downvote things.

Comment: If @downvoters would be kind enough to *leave a comment to help OP improve their question* instead of drive-by downvoting that would be awesome :) I see nothing wrong with the question, it's an architecture question about error propagation throughout the application layer, and is very well-written.

Comment: @DocBrown language clarification would definitely make it far more on-topic, good call!

Comment: I took the freedom to edit your question into a form which avoids further downvotes for the reasons listed [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/why-questions-about-the-correct-way-are-too-broad).  Please double check if I got your intentions right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General Principles of Error Handling

Exceptions should be handled in the layer of code that can actually do something about the error.

The "log and rethrow" pattern is often considered an [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639963/why-is-log-and-throw-considered-an-anti-pattern) (for exactly the reason you mentioned, leads to a lot of duplicate code and doesn't really help you do anything practical.)

The point of an exception is that it is "not expected".  If the layer of code you are working in can't do something reasonable to continue successful processing when the error happens, just let it bubble up.

If the layer of code you are working in ***can*** do something to continue when the error happens, that is the spot to handle the error.  (And returning a "failed" http response code counts as a way to "continue processing".  You are saving the program from crashing.)

### Node.js web server error handling (using a library like Koa/Express)

I would strongly recommend using a framework like [Koa.js](https://koajs.com/#introduction) 
(the "successor" to the very popular [Express](http://expressjs.com/) framework) if you are building an http server in Node.js.

These frameworks give you a very clean and simple toolset to build up your webapi with ease.  (and they both give you default error handling out of the box)

- [Koa default error handling.](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/HEAD/docs/error-handling.md)
- [Express default error handling.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is to let the exception bubble up and the webserver will convert it to a 500 with error message.

You can improve upon this by hiding the error message from non-local connections.

You can improve upon that by having an unhandler exception handler which logs all unhandled errors.

Now, whether you can do that in node or not I don't know.

.. Ok Just reading up and.. omg node crashes if it gets an unhandled error?!?!?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling

So the answer is follow the crazy complicated and flawed error event stuff or upgrade to a sensible language/webserver

Comment: Of course node.js crashes if it gets an unhandled error.  What would you expect it to do?  It is just a basic code runtime environment.  Would you expect a Java console program to not crash on an unhandled exception?  The better suggestion for node would be to use a library like express/koa to handle the basic http server stuff.  And setup a basic error handling middlewear handle exception cases.

Comment: The information behind the link is fine in this answer, but everything else does not seem to apply to node.js. And "use a different web server" is pretty much a non-answer.

Comment: I'd expect that call to crash and return an error code, while the envrionment continues to accept and process other calls

Comment: @doc it seems to me that 'use another web server' _is_ the answer here. This question would not come up in asp or php or ruby on rails etc because the framework provides the basic function of unhandled exception processing.

Comment: Its not always that simple, as shared resources (e.g. DB connections from the connection pool) might be in a bad state. I've written something about what I think the best strategy is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528705/exception-handling-thrown-errors-within-promises/19540907#19540907

Comment: ie. from a software architecture perspective, the solution should be at the webserver level, not in your code

Comment: I completely agree with your answer @gorgikosev whats missing is a framework to properly handle web requests. It simply shouldnt be possible for page level code to crash the webserver so easily

Comment: @ewan - asp != .net, Ruby "on rails" != Ruby.  Those are frameworks on top of the code "runtime environment".  Node.js is the runtime environment.  Express (a framework in node.js) DOES handle errors automatically for you.  https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: @caleb sure I think thats what im saying in my answer. nodejs fails as a webserver by itself

Comment: Related (on Quora): [What are the pros and cons of Node.js versus Apache web server?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-Node-js-versus-Apache-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this question for years already, the best thing I've come to far, is to wrap each such function call in *try/catch* and return a special type of error instance depending on the layer at which it happened.

It is more complex than one generic error handler, but gives more flexibity and in practice works quite satisfactorily.

By the way, *Fastify* can help a bit to avoid writing boilerplate for generating proper error response for the client, because it does it automatically if handler function returs *Error* instance (instance that extends *Error* and holds response status)

Comment: I logged in specifically to comment here. No, this is not what you want to do and avoid this pattern at all costs. Don't encapsulate the error in another Error object.

Also, do not install another library and expect it to handle all the exception handling for you.